# What should we do about these newly created tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I just noticed on the [Moderation Tools](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tools) page that many new tags have been created recently (all by the same user):

[image: New tags]

Many of these are IMHO unnecessary (like [copyright](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright) or [date](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date)) or just duplicates (like [airport-chart](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airport-chart) of [aeronautical-charts](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aeronautical-charts) or [sid](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sid) of [departure-sid](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/departure-sid) / [sid-star](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sid-star)).

Normally I just remove or replace these new tags from their questions, which will automatically delete them. In this case however, that would flood the homepage with many edits. **What should we do about this?**

Also: I really think the [300 reputation threshold](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) for creating tags is *way too low*, but I guess there is no way we can change this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For synonyms (ie, tags which mean the same thing) you can [suggest a synonym](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/airport-chart/synonyms). This is a helpful way to stop multiple tags which all mean the same thing.

For a tag like [date](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) they should just be removed - it is a metatag at best and has absolutely no meaning at worst.

For new questions already high up on the homepage, this is fine to edit straight away. We have asked in the past that old questions do not get edited in bulk as it does tend to flood the homepage and hide newer questions as we do not have a huge volume of questions being asked.

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup and creating synonyms. I see you left two new tags: I add some usage guidance for [takeoff-minimums](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/takeoff-minimums/info), but I'm not so sure about [beacon](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beacon). Do we want to include both ground beacons and aircraft beacon lights here?

Comment: @Bianfable I missed beacon, also cleaned up that one